# Create Clip Using Ableton Live Python API

Tags: python, midi, ableton-live

Is it possible to create a clip in the session view of Ableton Live programmatically using the Python API?

More context: I'm hacking a [MIDI Remote Script](http://remotescripts.blogspot.com) using the _Framework classes in. In response to an event trigger I want to fill a ClipSlot with a new midi clip.

The [Live Object Model](http://cycling74.com/docs/max5/refpages/m4l-ref/m4l_live_object_model.html#ClipSlot) seems pretty restrictive on `create` actions—is it even possible to programmatically create a clip in Ableton Live?

Comment: Seems likely to be impossible via Live API calls: https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=151056&hilit=create+clip+python

Comment: Update: seems that as of Live 9, Push's RemoteScript invokes an API method called `Track.duplicate_clip_slot`: http://julienbayle.net/PythonLiveAPI_documentation/Live.Track.Track.html

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is frowned upon or not, but I was trying to do the same thing, and apparently it's now possible to create a clip using `Live.ClipSlot.ClipSlot.create_clip()`

from http://julienbayle.net/PythonLiveAPI_documentation/Live9.1.xml (Decompiled Live 9.1 API)

> `Live.ClipSlot.ClipSlot.create_clip()` Method
>
> `create_clip( (ClipSlot)arg1, (float)arg2)` -> None :
>
> Creates an empty clip with the given length in the slot. Throws an error when called on non-empty slots or slots in non-MIDI >tracks. C++ signature : void create_clip(TPyHandle,double)